# Do I postback the whole array or just an element of the array when using AJAX?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery, viewmodel

I've not worked with AJAX outside of (AJAX Control Toolkit) for Webforms. So forgive my ignorance. But now that I'm working with MVC 3 and JQuery, I'd like to know what is the way to handle this issue. Basically, my page will GET a `List<ViewModel>`. But when I postback, do I postback the whole `List<ViewModel>` or just the one element that needs updating? What's the normal way to handle this? For now, just assume my ViewModel is:

```
public class activePlayer   
{
    public int UserID {get; set;};
    public string LastName {get; set;};
    public string FirstName {get; set;};
    public string Class {get; set;};
    public int XP {get; set;};
    public string activeWeapon {get; set;};
}
```

Comment: That (obviously) depends on what kind of user scenario you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Show a list of players and have an user update one player at a time.

Comment: If it is "one at a time" then you submit one model.

Answer (score 1):

Note, that the term "postback" is more relevant to ASP.net web forms. While using an MVC framework you will be making an "http post" to the desired route.

In regards to your question you probably would more than likely post the ID of the user that you need to edit to an Edit result:

```
Public ViewResult Edit(int id)
{
  activePlayer model = // lookup model here
  return View("Edit", model)
}
```

Which in turn will render an edit view:

```
@model <yourproject.Models.activePlayer>

@using(@Html.BeginForm())
{
  @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.UserID)
  <div>
    <div clas="editor-label>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.LastName)</div>
    <div clas="editor-field>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.LastName)</div>
  </div>
  <div>
    <div clas="editor-label>@Html.LabelFor(m => m.FirstName)</div>
    <div clas="editor-field>@Html.EditorFor(m => m.FirstName)</div>
  </div>
  // .. remaining fields
  <input type="submit" />
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is more of a form based view. Meaning that the user will be editing on the spot and not in a separate view.